# ASP.NET Web User Control(C#)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me in working with (multiple)WebUserControls. 
I have tried, but I am not clear with the events which we have  to use.

Comment: What is your question? What problems are you having?

Comment: Be specific in your Questions...

Comment: We have to use events in this case. I  have tried multiple sites where I can learn about Web User Control. But that information is not sufficient. Can you provide me some useful link for the same.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to add more details about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I want to use webusercontrol in my project. I have just started with ASP.NET. So, I have tries multiple web sites where I can learn about WebUserControl. Till now I am not Comfortable with the answers provided. So, can anyone help me by giving some useful link where I can thoroughly learn about WebUserControl.

Comment: @Jash. I hear you saying you want to use controls, but not pages. Learn the larger context of how asp.net pages work and then how controls fit into those pages will come naturally. Most of the questions I see regarding controls on SO are because the OP doesn't understand the page life cycle. (Why can't I access my control before it is available to the page).

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to understand is the [ASP.NET Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Once you learn the order of operations for how an httpRequest is received into ASP.NET and how the httpResponse is built and returned you have the essential information.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your Q [sharing controls across multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635725/sharing-user-controls-acrros-multiple-websites)

[check this too](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-user-control-in-aspnet)